How to style only negative values of the line chart in ngx-echart?
How can we show red line for negative values in the following chart?
I am able to style the dots that have negative values but when I try to style the connecting line , It seems like ngx-echart does not support it!?
chart link

The Problem is that each element displayed has it's own styles. The Line is one element for it self so it can only have one color. So for each case you want an element behave diffrently, you have to render one just for that case.
Alternativly (untested) you can apply a gradient color, but that seems even more complicate.

You can just use a visualMap. Take a look at this official example.
There seems to be an issue if pieces specify equal border values. But this should work:
Example
visualMap: {
  show: false,
  dimension: 1,
  seriesIndex: 0,
  pieces: [
    {lt: 0, color: 'red'},
    {gte: 0.00000000000001, color: 'blue'},
  ]
}

